# How do I suppress content type information when calling PHP from command line?

Tags: php, bash, content-type

I wrote a little PHP script that performs some MySQL transactions and is supposed to be run locally, instead of making it accessible via the web. I run this script by calling it via the prompt

```
php script.php param1 param2 param3
```

The script runs fine and returns the expected results as output to stdout. But the output starts with

```
Content-type: text/html
```

in the first line, which obviously is unwanted here. I already managed to change this to plain text

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

But I don't want this information in my output. How can I suppress it?

Comment: Does your script contain any `header()` calls? If so, simply remove them.

Comment: @AmalMurali Unwanted information comes in both cases, if I call them - and if not as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add -q argument like

```
php -q script.php param1 param2 param3
```

to suppress header information.

Running `php -h` will show you all arguments that it takes.

```
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s [-v] [-i] [-f <file>] | {<file> [args...]}
-q Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP Header output.
-s Display colour syntax highlighted source.
-f <file> Parse <file>. Implies '-q'
-v Version number
-C Do not chdir to the script directory
-c <path> Look for php.ini file in this directory
-a Run interactively
-d foo[=bar] Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
-e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
-z <file> Load Zend extension <file>.
-l Syntax check only (lint)
-m Show compiled in modules
-i PHP information
-h This help
```